# Differences between sending POST with AFNetworking and curl

Tags: ios, iphone, curl, afnetworking

I
ve been using AFNetworking 2 with success for some time, but I stumbled upon case where I don't know where to turn my head to. I have to make POST request in order to log in, send credentials alongside and receive JSON back with operation status. For some weird reason sending it via AFNetworking like this:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"login": self.loginField.text, @"password" : self.passField.text};
NSDictionary *data = @{@"data": params};
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
//manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:server parameters:@{@"data" : params} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}];
```

I have to pack dictionary with parameters as a single "data" parameter. I do get back OK 200, but if I take a look in server logs I see that no data was transferred, which ended up as user not recognized.
But if send with `curl` this:

```
curl -d 'data={"login":"xx", "password":"yy"}' http://someurl/api/login/
```

I got perfectly fine response and in logs I see some actual data. Does anyone know how to deal with such a case?

If it helps, I'm doing it in iPhone simulator, not tested on actual device.

Comment: I tried serializing response, request and both - no changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the `AFNetworking` source code, namely the class `AFJSONRequestSerializer`, you will see that the serialise function for that serialiser puts the parameters you hand over into the body - and not as an HTTP parameter as you expect.

You should use an **AFHTTPRequestSerializer** in your case - that will add the parameters as (URL-encoded) HTTP parameters to your URL.

Something like that should work in your case:

```
// build the JSON parameter string
NSDictionary *params = @{@"login": self.loginField.text, @"password" : self.passField.text};

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[jsonData bytes]
                                                length:[jsonData length]
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// and now send the JSON parameter string as HTTP parameter
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:server 
   parameters:@{@"data" : jsonString} 
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
          NSLog(@"success: %@", responseObject);
      }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
      }];
```

Comment: it's not making any difference, no matter if I use JSON serializer or HTTP serializer...or even if comment it out

Comment: That's strange, because the AFNetworking code does completely different things depending on the serialiser you choose ... Commenting out should use the HTTPSerializer.

Comment: Oh, I see it ... tell you in a few minutes, don't have time now

Comment: You have to serialise your params into a JSON object and then add that as a HTTP parameter to your request - if you use the JSONSerializer it will serialise the parameters to JSON, but add them as body, and if you use the HTTPSerializer, it will not serialise the parameters to JSON, but add them as HTPP parameters. So you have to mix both approaches :-).

Comment: shouldn't I put `NSDictionary` as parameters in GET - serializing on my own gives me `NSData`

Comment: No, you have to make a JSON string out of it, not NSData - with NSJSONSerialization.